# How to distinguish a Wikipedia article by URL?

Tags: regex, url, mediawiki, wikipedia

There are many pages on Wikipedia that are not articles, e.g. talk pages etc. How to distinguish them from articles by URL?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Talk pages have "Talk:" before the title, both in the title of the page and the URL.

Comment: Yes, but there are not only talk pages. I've tried to use only alpanumeric URLs, but that's obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of Wikipedia namespaces and their aliases by using its API with the following query:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces

Then, if the part of the page title before the first colon matches any of the known namespaces, it's not an article; otherwise, it is.

Comment: This list of namespaces above is insufficient, since MediaWiki also uses the something:something convention for interwiki links. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interwiki_links

Comment: @jpatokal The question asks about URLs. And while URLs like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cs:Main_Page do work, I think they're used only rarely.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that **you can't** with regexes alone.

The longer answer is that MediaWiki articles are divided by namespace, which in turn use colons as markers, as in "Talk:Foo".  Articles *without* a colon in the title are thus definitely in the main (= content) namespace.  Problem is, articles with a colon may either be in another namespace, *or* be [content articles that happen to contain a colon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aNaming_conventions_%28technical_restrictions%29#Colons), and since WP's list of namespaces is long and ever-changing you can't (or at least shouldn't) hardcode this list in a regex.

The correct answer is thus to use the [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page) to iterate/search for articles in the main namespace only.

Comment: This double meaning of colon is exactly the thing that got me stuck!

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode the list of namespaces, but what about using the API to get an up-to-date list (see my answer)?

Comment: Why not just use the API to get a prefiltered list of articles that are all guaranteed to be from the main namespace? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Using_list.3Dallpages_as_generator